# Google Cloud Functions - Realtime Database Trigger - how to deserialize data JSON to POJO?

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, gson

As described on the Google Cloud Functions [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database#code_sample), it is possible to trigger a Function based on Firebase Realtime Database events (write/create/update/delete).

The following docs [sample](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database#code_sample) explains how to get the **delta** snapshot.

```
public class FirebaseRtdb implements RawBackgroundFunction {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FirebaseRtdb.class.getName());

  // Use GSON (https://github.com/google/gson) to parse JSON content.
  private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

  @Override
  public void accept(String json, Context context) {
    logger.info("Function triggered by change to: " + context.resource());

    JsonObject body = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);

    boolean isAdmin = false;
    if (body != null && body.has("auth")) {
      JsonObject authObj = body.getAsJsonObject("auth");
      isAdmin = authObj.has("admin") && authObj.get("admin").getAsBoolean();
    }

    logger.info("Admin?: " + isAdmin);

    if (body != null && body.has("delta")) {
      logger.info("Delta:");
      logger.info(body.get("delta").toString());
    }
  }
}
```

The sample works perfectly but the question is: **How can I deserialize this delta to a POJO?**

I tried:

```
val mObject = gson.fromJson(body.get("delta").toString(), MyCustomObject::class.java)
```

But I am getting:

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT`

As far as I know it is because MyObject class has a `List<T>` field, and Firebase Database always convert Lists to Maps with integer keys.

I preferably do not want to change every `List<T>` to `Map<Int,T>`, because I have a lot of classes :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are trying to read the data in Android?

Comment: No, I am reading it on a Cloud Function (RawBackgroundFunction), just like in the sample, but using Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I ended up doing *(maybe not the best solution!)*:

**1)** Create a custom Json Deserializer for Firebase-coming lists:

```
class ListFirebaseDeserializer<T> : JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<T>> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): ArrayList<T> {
        val result = ArrayList<T>()
        val typeOfElement = (typeOfT as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]

        json?.let {
            json.asJsonObject.entrySet().forEach {
                entry->
                result.add(Gson().fromJson(entry.value, typeOfElement))
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

This takes the lists that Firebase turned into maps and convert it back to actual lists.

**2)** Annotate every list in my POJO with `@JsonAdapter(ListFirebaseDeserializer::class)`, for instance:

```
class MyCustomObject {

    @JsonAdapter(ListFirebaseDeserializer::class)
    var myPaymentList = ArrayList<Payment>()
}
```

It could be a pain if you already have lots of lists to annotate, but it is better than having to use maps instead.

*Hope it helps!*